# vim snippet default snippet file issue

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I installed Vundle, got the snippetMate running. But when vim launched, the snippet it loaded is _.snippets. With my Understanding, it is the default for snippet. However, i want to use other snippet such as sh.snippets and tex.snippets. I try to run the SnippetMateOpenFile in Vim to locate the snippets file It doesn't appear. I checked and see that all of the snippet file is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `_.snippets` contains the global snippets. In order to use the other ones, the correct *filetype* has to be set. The snippet plugin reuses the same mechanism that Vim uses for syntax highlighting and settings (like indent) that are specific to a certain programming language. Usually, filetype detection works automatically; you can check with

```
:verbose setlocal filetype?
```

This needs to print `sh` for shell scripts, to use `sh.snippets`. If it doesn't, you have to fix / enable filetype detection (see `:help filetype-detect`), or, for a one-time fix, set it manually:

```
:setf sh
```

(I'm not sure about your particular snippet plugin; I guess it's *snipMate*, but there are multiple variants around.)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened. the snippets won't recognize the snippet files rightaway. So i saved and exit the text and reopen vim again. It works, yet seems like there must be a certain tag in order for vim to recognize the format of the file.